# On content delivery server, /-/jssmedia link breaks, /-/media link works

Tags: jss

We have deployed a jss app to a Content Delivery server.

We have followed instructions to add jss support to the server role.

Links to media items generated by Image components begin with `/-/jssmedia` and 404.

Changing the generated urls to start with `/-/media` makes them serve an image.

The error in the logs for broken links is this:

```
3392 11:43:27 ERROR Application error.
Exception: System.Web.HttpException
Message: The file '/-/jssmedia/cms-sitecore/data/media/img/sitecorejss_media.ashx' does not exist.
Source: System.Web
   at System.Web.UI.Util.CheckVirtualFileExists(VirtualPath virtualPath)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultInternal(VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultWithNoAssert(HttpContext context, VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResult(HttpContext context, VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)
   at System.Web.UI.SimpleHandlerFactory.System.Web.IHttpHandlerFactory2.GetHandler(HttpContext context, String requestType, VirtualPath virtualPath, String physicalPath)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.MaterializeHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

#### IIS Handler Mappings

On the Content Delivery server, IIS Site > Handler Mappings shows the sitecore_media.ashx endpoint. It does not have a sitecorejss_media.ashx endpoint.

On a Content Management server, where the images are showing up, the sitecorejss_media.ashx endpoint is registered.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What we did:

Located the file `Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.MediaRequestHandler.jssconfig` in the App_Config directory.

Pulled out the line where it defines the handler, and added it to end of the system.webServer/handlers section of the root web.config.

The patch looks like this:

```
      <add verb="*" path="sitecore_expeditor_speak_request_async.ashx" type="Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.Speak.Server.RequestAsyncHandler, Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.Speak" name="Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.Speak.Server.RequestAsyncHandler" />
      <add verb="*" path="sitecorejss_media.ashx" type="Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.Media.MediaRequestHandler, Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.Media" name="Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.Media.MediaRequestHandler" />
    </handlers>
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is if you didn't install the `Headless Services module` the normal way on that environment then you have to manually update the `Web.config` as per

https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/hd/201/sitecore-headless-development/media-handler.html

Answer (score 0):

We had this same issue but in containers.

What is missing is somehow the handler that is written in "Sitecore.XA.Foundation.MediaRequestHandler.sxaconfig" file in /App_Config folder is not getting applied to the web.config file. So for non-docker setup we can simply copy the below line and add it to 'system.webServer/handlers' section of the root web.config.

```
<add patch:instead="*[@type='Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaRequestHandler, Sitecore.Kernel']" verb="*" path="sitecore_media.ashx" type="Sitecore.XA.Foundation.MediaRequestHandler.MediaRequestHandler, Sitecore.XA.Foundation.MediaRequestHandler" name="Sitecore.MediaRequestHandler" />
```

Now if you are using Docker as in our case, we wrote a xdt for the same and it worked for us.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add verb="*" path="sitecorejss_media.ashx" type="Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.Media.MediaRequestHandler, Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.Media"
         name="Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.Media.MediaRequestHandler" xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing" xdt:Locator="Match(name)" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```